# Adding variable whitespace between text in a <li> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having the following code:

```
for(i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++)
{
  $('#entries').append("<li>" + results.rows.item(i).food +
                       "<span class = 'addWhiteSpace'>" +
                       results.rows.item(i).calories + " caloriën" + "</span>" +
                       "</li>");
}
```

I already added a span with class whitespace and set the CSS to `margin-left: 50px`.
The problem with that is that the whitespaces are all the same, so the position of the span depends of the result from my WebSQL database (`results.rows.item(i).food`).

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. It seems to me that since you are trying to display tabular data the appropriate html structure is a `<table>`, but if you must use `<li>` elements try putting your span around the variable width data, i.e., around your `...food` text rather than around the `...calories`.

Comment: Give some fixed height and width to span ...

Comment: the li items are appended to a ul. Food returns a value from a database, in this case text. The text has a variable length, so if I want to add whitespace via the margin-left property of the span, they all have a variable length and aren't aligned properly.

Comment: You still forgot to ask an actual question, but assuming you are trying to ask "How do I make them align?", did you try my previous suggestion yet?

Comment: Yeah my question was indeed: "How do I make them align?" So the calorie values begin on the same right-margin distance. I put the span around the food-value but what kind of CSS do i have to use then?

Comment: If the food values are inside spans that all have the same width then the calorie values would left align.

Comment: My code is now this: 

$('#entries').append("<li>" + "<span style ='width:500px;'>" +             results.rows.item(i).food + "</span>" + results.rows.item(i).calories + " calories" +  "</li>"); 

If i run it in Ripple, it still has the same lay-out. Here is a picture:

[link]http://img842.imageshack.us/img842/2914/probleemmetjquery.jpg

I just want the lay-out that the calories start on the same left-margin, on a variable distance of the food.

Comment: @nnnnnn, thank you very much for all the effort you put into my question ;-)

Comment: What is the aversion to placing the content into a table (where it belongs)?  Your problem would be instantly solved by doing the semantically correct thing here.

Comment: Hmmmm i didn't knew that in this case, a table is semantically the most correct thing. So I make a table, some rows and cells and than i can set the correct width. Sounds pretty logic! I'm gonna try it now :)

Comment: @cimmanon, thank you very much! Putting the variables in a table worked like a charm! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely agree with @nnnnnn's comments above.

You are displaying **tabular data** therefore you should be using the `<table>` construct.  This will automatically deal with the variable width's of your data, and display it as you expect the data to be.